# Submit form if action == something

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to submit a `<form>` automatically if:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] =='confirmado')){
```

submit form.

I don´t know if I should use a javascript script.
I try doing this but it is not working.

```
<script>

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] =='confirmado')){
    $("#form").submit(function(){
    document.form.submit(); 
    return false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the data flow of your pages.

Comment: Given that browsers implement JavaScript, and not PHP, yes, I think you should use JavaScript `:P`

Comment: Automatically when? On page load? On button press?

Comment: Where is `$_POST['action']` coming from?

Comment: When I submit a dialog, it goes to this page with the action CONFIRMADO.   So I just want the page to submit a form if the POST['action'] is confirmado.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mix up PHP, which is a `server-side language`, with Javascript, which is a `client-side language`. So, that won't work.

Moreover, the submission of a `<form>` is NOT captured in its $_POST array as $POST['action']. The method of submission is `POST` and the `$_POST` array contains data submitted via the form's html elements.

Comment: So with PHP? how can I submit a <form>  if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] =='confirmado'))

Comment: First, where is `$_POST['action']` coming from? Is it a name of a HTML element thats in the form? Or, are you referring to the action attribute of the `<form>` element?

Comment: When I submit a dialog, it goes to this page with the action CONFIRMADO. So I just want the page to submit a form if the POST['action'] is confirmado.

Comment: Does the text/label on the dialog's submit button read 'confirmado'?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( '#form' ).submit(function () {
    if ( this.action !== 'confirmado' ) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with coder1984: you are mixing PHP with Javascript, and you are trying to access POST data in the client side, which is not possible. If I can guess what you are trying to do, maybe this code will help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (<?php echo (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] =='confirmado')) ? '1' : '0'; ?>) {
  document.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your code right, you would like to only submit the form if the field "action" equals "confirmando". Since you are allready using jQuery let's keep at it.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('input[name=action]').change(function() {
                if($(this).val() == 'confirmando') {
                    $('form').submit(); // If you would like to do a normal sumbit
                    $.post('my_php_file.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data)) { // or use AJAX
                        /* var data now contains the output of the PHP file  */
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It still makes sense to check the submited form in PHP when you receive the data from the form.